# _CrtSetAllocHook callback requestNumber is always 0 when _HOOK_FREE

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-profiling

I'm using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetallochook?view=msvc-160 to get some memory statistics on my app and everything seems fine except I can't map allocations with deallocations.

When `allocType == _HOOK_ALLOC` or `allocType == _HOOK_REALLOC` I get null `userData` (because it's not allocated yet) and non zero `requestNumber` and when `allocType == _HOOK_FREE` I get non null `userData`, but 0 `requestNumber` in the callback.

The code is quite simple:

```
_CrtSetAllocHook(&MemoryTracker::CrtAllocHook);
...

int MemoryTracker::CrtAllocHook(int                  allocType,
                                void*                userData,
                                size_t               size,
                                int                  blockType,
                                long                 requestNumber,
                                const unsigned char* filename,
                                int                  lineNumber)
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/allocation-hooks-and-c-run-time-memory-allocations?view=vs-2019
    if (blockType == _CRT_BLOCK)
        return TRUE;
    // Track allocations/deallocations here...
```

How to map allocations to deallocations? I would expect to have same `requestNumber` when deallocating to be able to know for which allocation I get the deallocation.

Comment: you can use `(((_CrtMemBlockHeader *)userData)-1)` for get pointer for [`_CrtMemBlockHeader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2019) and here exist *lRequest - Allocation number* from [re]alloc

Comment: @RbMm I can't find the definition of ```_CrtMemBlockHeader``` - ```in crtdbg.h``` it's just a declaration. I also couldn't find its header in the docs....

Comment: Found it in the docs - ```dbgint.h```